# Snap SVG translate element that has rotation

Tags: svg, rotation, transformation, snap.svg

I am trying to move (translate) an object that has been rotated, when I move (translate) the rotated object it loses it's rotation and does move correctly.  If the use the same code on an object that is not rotated then the move correctly.  What I am doing wrong here?

Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fractorr/d27cf/3/)

This code loses the rotation.

```
var part = s.select("#part_2");
var t = new Snap.Matrix();
t.translate(part.getBBox().x,part.getBBox().y+18);
part.transform(t);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what order you want the transforms to apply. If you want the squares to move such that down is applied after transforming i.e. down for the rotated matrix is at an angle you'd do this...

```
    var t = part.transform().localMatrix;
    t.translate(0, 18);
    part.transform(t);
```

If, however you want down to always be down then you'd do something like this...

```
    var t = new Snap.Matrix();
    t.translate(0, 18);
    t.add(part.transform().localMatrix);
    part.transform(t);
```

The trick is to get the existing matrix for the shape and append/prepend the transform you want to it.

Comment: So then t.add(part.transform().localMatrix); essentially just makes it so the translate is added to the existing transforms instead or clearing the existing transforms?

Comment: Yes, localMatrix is the existing transform.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed, also fixed a couple other issues I was having in my app.

Comment: This is so key to working with Inkscape SVG output and yet I couldn't find this info anywhere else. TY!